# Group by based on field length

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wanted to group number of ids that are of length of 4, 5, 6 bytes based on the year.

| ID | year | name | location | geo | new_loc | addr 1 | addr 2 | addr 3 | addr 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2019 | bob | UK | UK-4 | basic | dat1 | dat11 | dat13 | dat123 |
| 19804 | 2004 | sam | US | US-1 | advanced | dat2 | dat21 | dat23 | dat233 |
| 19 | 2000 | lister | EU | EU | basic | dat3 | dat31 | dat33 | dat333 |
| 190838 | 2004 | harold | US | US-3 | basic | dat4 | dat41 | dat53 | dat533 |
| 11804 | 2019 | beanie | SK | UK-2 | advanced | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

**Output**

| ID | year | name | location | new location | num_of_ids_each_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2019 | bob | UK | basic | 2 |
| 11804 | 2019 | beanie | SK | advanced | 2 |
| 19804 | 2004 | sam | US | advanced | 2 |
| 190838 | 2004 | harold | US | basic | 2 |

What I tried:

```
select ID, year, name, location, [new location], count(year)
from table1
group by ID, year, name, location, [new location], count(year);
```

Could someone advice on how to include only those ids that has more than 4,5,6 bytes

Comment: use `len()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I'm aware of len ( ) but i'm unaware of the right position to use it since we are coupling the query with group by here.

Comment: you wanted `ids that has more than 4,5,6 bytes` so add a `WHERE` clause `WHERE LEN(ID) in (4,5,6)`

Comment: select ID, year, name, location, new location, count(year)
from table1
group by ID, year, name, location, new location, count(year) where len(ID) IN (4,5,6) 
-------is not giving the right yield.

Comment: should be `SELECT ... FROM table1 WHERE len(ID) in (4,5,6) GROUP BY ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Squirrel, I finally made a way.

```
select id, Year, name, location, [new location], 
    count(id) over (partition by year) as num_of_ids_each_year
from table1 where len(id) in (4,5,6);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COUNT()` with `Partition by Year` to get the results without using `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT ID, [year], [name], [location], [new location]
    , COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY year) AS num_of_ids_each_year
FROM table1
WHERE LEN(ID) IN (4,5,6)
```

Comment: You are right!! i fixed it, it's exactly the same i did it.

Comment: would be great if you could accept this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try aggregate function in having clause

e.g.

```
select  ID, 
        year, 
        name, 
        location, 
        new location, 
        len(year)
from table1
group by ID, year, name, location, new location
having Len(year) >= 4
```